# i am trying to get data from input box and pass it to the database need help not able to get result

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get data from input box and pass it to the database to show appropriate records and results but need help not able to get result

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php>
$prod_name = $_POST["name_of_the_product"];
echo [$prod_name];
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "acwj_price";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "acwj_price";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Please Try Again");
mysql_select_db("wikiacwj_price") or die ("no data");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM price_comparsion where product_name="prod_name"");

//write the results

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo $row['product_name'];}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Warning: CARGO CULT PROGRAMMING DETECTED!. You've got syntax errors galore, you've got SQL injection holes, you've got useless error handling, blah blah blah. In other words, the code is a mess.

1) `echo [$prod_name];` what are the `[]` for here? This is a flat out syntax error

2) mysql_connect("$db_host" etc...  - why the `""` around variables? You'r creating a new empty string, embedding another string inside that - a total waste of cpu cycles.

3) `or die ("Please Try Again");`  - of what use is it to tell your site's user to try again? If your code can't log into mysql, how is the user supposed to fix this? Hammering on reload won't make an invalid mysql login magically start working again. If you're the only user of the code, at least have a useful error message output, explaining why the script is dying, e.g. `or die(mysql_error())`.

4) `... where product_name="prod_name"")`. You've got another horrendous syntax error here - you cannot embed quotes within a string that is built with the same type of quotes you're trying to embed.

4a) Should that be `... product_name='$prod_name'"`, perhaps, so you're actually embedding the form value that was passed in?

4b) `$prod_name` is now your SQL injection source, and you should have AT MINIMUIM `$prod_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name_of_product'])`, and have it somewhere AFTER you connect to the DB, since m_r_e_s() only works when you have an active DB connection.

Comment: Haha, you beat me to the punch. Well, 5 is incorrect, he does have a matching }. Right here: `echo $row['product_name'];}` But yeah, I was going to mention 1, 2, the latter half of 3, and 4.

Comment: Woops right... The glare of the other errors covered that up. Removing 5).

Comment: In 4, please note that you can use the same quotes in a string provided you escape them.

Answer (score 2):

We need more context to give you a solid answer, however reviewing your code I've found the following things that are causing problems:

`echo [$prod_name];` is incorrect - should be `echo $prod_name;`

Also, the mysql_connect is incorrect - should be:  `mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass) or die ("Please Try Again");`
*(you should not have quotes around the variables)*

And the sql statement is incorrect - should be:
`$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM price_comparsion where product_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($prod_name) . "'");`
*(corrected the quoting, changed to pass in the variable, and added `mysql_real_escape_string` as minimum sql error prevention)*

Note: This does NOT reflect best practices with SQL - there's all sorts of SQL Injection attack vulnerabilities in the original code - this code is only revised to work.  If you will be writing code like this, you should should read about SQL Injection prevention.  There's plenty of good information on StackOverflow - here's just one example: [SQL Injection, Quotes and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030428/sql-injection-quotes-and-php)